# Do I have to internationalise the display of hexadecimal values?

Tags: internationalization

For decimal numbers, obviously I want to localise everything. Whatever programming language I'm working in, there will tend to be tools for this, so it's also easy to do.

In my application, I happen to be formatting numbers as hexadecimal quite often. This leads me to wonder:

- Are there locales which group hexadecimal numbers into different groupings to me?
- Are there locales which use a separator other than space for the groupings?
- Are A-F used as the extra six digits even in locales which don't use a Latin script?

I guess in general - do I have to internationalise this, or does everyone in the world look at the same hexadecimal value and intrinsically understand it the same way?

Comment: Who is the end user? If it is programmers/technologists, its reasonable not to internationalist as the notation is universal within the programming community.

Comment: Programmers and forensics people. But I'm wary because I used to say "something as universal as kB would never be localised, would it?" too.

Comment: You group hex numbers? How? Why?

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ becauseit'sveryhardtoreadthingswhentheyaremashedtogetherwithnospaces (and with hex, usually groups of 2 or 4 digits.)

Comment: @Trejkaz: you group them in some way that's convenient for you, so it's unlikely that everyone else groups them the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Generic answer: If the requirements are not clear, or unknown, you can approach this in two ways. The first is YAGNI, and don't do it. The other is to plan ahead and create a locale for displaying Hex numbers, and only implement a single format.

In your case, given the target audience, I would spend a short (something over a second, less than a minute is about right) amount of time asking the product owner for requirements, and then apply YAGNI. The reason for asking is so you don;t get blamed for not implementing a requirement you did not know about, and have evidence you planned ahead.

Comment: The most amusing thing I think about this answer is the implication that we have some kind of product owners, or people who know the requirements when they file the tickets. How much easier would software development be if this were the case! lol...  Not saying the answer is bad, though.